# What does this bold letter preceeded ny a roman numeral indicate?

Tags: sheet-music, classical-guitar, roman-numerals

I'm trying to read this etude by Coste and frequently I find a bold B followed by a roman numeral in the score. What exactly does this indicate? Thanks. Here is the score: http://www.classclef.com/pdf/Opus%2038%20No%201%20by%20Napoleon%20Coste.pdf .

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think this is necessarily the best notation for it, but the B just stands for “barre” and the Roman numeral is a fret number. BV means that you should barre the fifth fret to perform the bracketed chunk of music. Later, 1/2B is used to indicate a partial barre where only the top few strings are barred at the indicated fret while the lower strings are left open.